# How to build GCC ARM project with hard restrictions to link libgcc?

Tags: gcc, arm, libc, nano, newlib

Im has found, what even with `--specs.nano.specs --specs.nosys.lib` will link `libgcc`, if some dependencies request it (like some float operations).

With `-nostdlib` flag, compiler will throw out `newlib-nano` too and obiviusly fail on build.

So the question is - how to save ability to link `newlib-nano`, but get error if some entity request any code what `newlib-nano` havent, but`libgcc` have?

Comment: gcclib and libc are two completely different things. are the float operations from gcclib?  please provide a simple example (should only take a few lines of code,but most important are the command lines).

Comment: @old_timer im fix main post. Yes, the talk is about libgcc. Idk how to provide a code, cause it about external library linking with cmake and its options.

Comment: You can use '-nostdlib' and then manually link with 'libgcc-nano'.  Note that 'newlib' is a no-OS version of the 'c library'.  There are many libc for Linux.  musl, bionic, uclibc, dietlibc, glibc, etc, but only newlib for 'baremetal' afaik.   If you are manually linking, you need to look into the internals of the compiler.  Also, you can define your own variants of some functions (stubbing them), if for instance is **guaranteed** not to need the behaviour.  Of course you play with fire when you do so.  Read docs and relevant source.  Not an answer that ChatGPT will give.

Comment: The deleted ChatGPT answer does seem to have the context/idea as the last sentence, now that I look.  +1 ChatGPT.